# Tenho um formulário dentro do outro e não consigo pegar o formulário mais interno

Tags: javascript, html, html5, javascript-eventos

Aqui esta um exemplo de como o formulário é, ele é muito mais complexo que isso, já tem quase 10 anos de uso e não tenho tempo de modificar tudo. Mas preciso ter acesso ao formulário que está dentro do outro, ou seja o formulário que esta com o id='form2'.

```
<form action='pagina1.php' method='post' id='form1'>
    <input type='text' name='teste' value='teste'>
    <input type='submit' name='enviar' value='enviar'>

    <form action='pagina2.php' method='post' id='form2'>
       <input type='text' name='teste' value='teste'>
       <input type='submit' name='enviar' value='enviar'>
    </form>
</form>
```

Formas que já tentei acessar esse formulário para envia-lo:

1. Clicando no button subimit mais externo ele enviar o formulario 1.
2. Criando um button no form2 com onclick e chamando uma função javascript passando como parâmetro um this.form ele identifica o formulario 1.
3. dando um document.ElementById("form2"), ele simplesmente não acha o meu formulario 2.
4. Mas quando dou um document.ElementById("form1") ele retorna o formulario 1.

alguém sabe porque isso esta acontecendo e como resolver esse problema ?

Comment: algum motivo especifico pra colocar um form dentro do outro?

Comment: Existem erros de sintaxe no seu código: `'name='enviar'`, há um caractere `'` antes do atributo `name` que compromete todo o restante do código. Corrija isso. Ressaltando o comentário anterior: não tem muita lógica criar um formulário dentro de outro (ao meu ver).

Comment: Não, como eu disse já tem 10 anos de uso, e na época eu não trabalhava aqui, agora o porque fazer assim não sei a necessidade, pela visão que tenho aqui não teria necessidade...

Comment: entao voce ja tem sua resposta man... separa esses dois forms..

Comment: Não, você não pode ter [formulários](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element) aninhados

Comment: Separei os dois formulários, coloquei um abaixo do outro ai deu certo. Muito obrigado pessoal !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elementos `form` não podem ser aninhados. Na [recomendação W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element), como Lucas postou nos comentários, diz:

> Flow content, but with **no form element descendants**.

Como prova prática disso, basta verificar no inspetor do navegador. Rode o código:

```html
<form action='pagina1.php' method='post' id='form1'>
  <input type='text' name='teste' value='teste'>
  <input type='submit' name='enviar' value='enviar'>

  <form action='pagina2.php' method='post' id='form2'>
    <input type='text' name='teste' value='teste'>
    <input type='submit' name='enviar' value='enviar'>
  </form>
</form>
```

Abra o inspetor do navegador (<kbd>F12</kbd>) e analise o código. Verá algo como:

[image: Código HTML no inspetor do navegador]

Perceba que o segundo formulário foi completamente ignorado pelo navegador ao carregar os elementos do DOM, o que explica `document.getElementById("form2")` retornar `null`, pois o elemento não existe no DOM, de fato.