# Enviar formulário modal sobre um formulário normal

Tags: javascript, html

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Tenho um formulário de cadastro e nele tem um link (*já possui conta*) que executa outro formulário (*login*), sendo este um modal. Meu problema é que, ao tentar enviar/submeter o formulário modal (*login*), ele exige que seja preenchido os campos do formulário normal (cadastro) que estava aberto, porque este formulário de cadastro requer alguns campos obrigatórios. Como proceder?

**formulário cadastro.php**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row espacamento">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <form role="form" method="POST" action="confirmacao.php">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <legend>Cadastro</legend>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <label for="first_name">Nome completo
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome" id="name" placeholder="Nome completo" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="first_name">Data de Nascimento
                        </label>
                        <div class='input-group date'>
                            <input type='text' name ="datanasc" id="datanasc" class="form-control datanasc"/>
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <label for="first_name">Endereço
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="endereco" id="endereco" placeholder="Endereço" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label>Cidade</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cidade" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="country">UF</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="estado" id="country">
                            <option value="estado">Selecione o Estado</option> 
                            <option value="Acre">Acre</option> 
                            <option value="Alagoas">Alagoas</option> 
                            <option value="Amazonas">Amazonas</option> 
                            <option value="Amapá">Amapá</option> 
                            <option value="Bahia">Bahia</option> 
                            <option value="Ceará">Ceará</option> 
                            <option value="Distrito Federal">Distrito Federal</option> 
                            <option value="Espírito Santo">Espírito Santo</option> 
                            <option value="Goiás">Goiás</option> 
                            <option value="Maranhão">Maranhão</option> 
                            <option value="Mato Grosso">Mato Grosso</option> 
                            <option value="Mato Grosso do Sul">Mato Grosso do Sul</option> 
                            <option value="Minas Gerais">Minas Gerais</option> 
                            <option value="Pará">Pará</option> 
                            <option value="Paraíba">Paraíba</option> 
                            <option value="Paraná">Paraná"</option> 
                            <option value="Pernambuco">Pernambuco</option> 
                            <option value="Piauí">Piauí</option> 
                            <option value="Rio de Janeiro">Rio de Janeiro</option> 
                            <option value="Rio Grande do Norte">Rio Grande do Norte</option> 
                            <option value="Rondônia">Rondônia</option> 
                            <option value="Rio Grande do Sul">Rio Grande do Sul</option> 
                            <option value="Roraima">Roraima</option> 
                            <option value="Santa Catarina">Santa Catarina</option> 
                            <option value="Sergipe">Sergipe</option> 
                            <option value="São Paulo">São Paulo</option> 
                            <option value="Tocantins">Tocantins</option> 
                        </select>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label>Telefone</label>
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control telefone" id="telefone" name="tel"  maxlength="15" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="mascara2(this, mtel2);" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="password">Senha</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="senha" id="password" placeholder="Senha" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="password">Confirme a senha</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="repetesenha" id="repetir_senha" placeholder="Confirme sua Senha..."
                               oninput="validaSenha(this)" required>            
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <!--CHAMANDO O MODAL-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button type="submit" name="enviar" class="btn corbotao">Cadastrar</button>
                        <?php include 'login-conta.php';?>                      
                    </div>                  
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**login-conta.php (modal)**

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal-mensagem">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content espacamento">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Acesso</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form name="fomrlogin" role="form" method="POST" action="confirm-login.php">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                            <label>E-mail</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="password">Senha</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="senha" id="password" placeholder="Senha" required>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn corbotao">Entrar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
                <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-mensagem" href="">Já possui uma conta?</a>
```

Comment: Primeiro, edite a pergunta acessando o link [edit] e insira o código HTML. Utilize o botão `{}` do editor para formatar corretamente o código. É preferível ainda que faça um [mcve] e, neste caso, pode utilizar o *snippet* do site através do botão `</>` do editor.

Comment: Anderson obrigado pela dica. Ver agora após edição.

Comment: login-conta.php é o meu moldal. É uma tela para acessar o sistema. Não é carregado nada dentro dela, apenas os codigos do moldal. Ela é chamada ao clicar em "já possui uma conta"

Comment: Você está carregando o formulário de login dentro do formulário de cadastro e isso não é possível. Veja mais em [Tenho um formulário dentro do outro e não consigo pegar o formulário mais interno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/200949/5878). Ou seja, os formulários não estão separados.

Comment: Obrigado Anderson, então, concluindo, não é possivel o Moldal sobre o formulário de cadastro.

Comment: É, basta você fazer o `include` **fora** do formulário de cadastro. Pode ser diretamente dentro da `div.container`.

Comment: Obrigado. Mudei o local do include e deu certo. Grato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você está inserindo um formulário dentro de outro formulário e isso não é permitido. Já comentei sobre isso aqui:

[Tenho um formulário dentro do outro e não consigo pegar o formulário mais interno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/200949/5878)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row espacamento">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <form role="form" method="POST" action="confirmacao.php">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <legend>Cadastro</legend>
                    </div>

                    ...

                </fieldset>

                <!--CHAMANDO O MODAL-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button type="submit" name="enviar" class="btn corbotao">Cadastrar</button>
                        <?php include 'login-conta.php';?>                      
                    </div>                  
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Perceba que seu `include` está 3 linhas antes de você encerrar o formulário de cadastro. Para contornar o problema, basta você inserir o `include` em outro lugar do HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row espacamento">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <form role="form" method="POST" action="confirmacao.php">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <legend>Cadastro</legend>
                    </div>

                    ...

                </fieldset>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button type="submit" name="enviar" class="btn corbotao">Cadastrar</button>             
                    </div>                  
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php include 'login-conta.php';?>   
</div>
```

Por exemplo, na penúltima linha, dentro do elemento `div.container`. Então provavelmente você vai precisar reposicionar o link "*Já possui uma conta?*", colocando-o diretamente no arquivo `cadastro.php`.

Comment: Quem votou negativo poderia se justificar?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado nem se esquente com isso :D